# PDF inline content is not visible showing blocked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pdf, jira, jira-plugin

I have created one Jira Plugin using Spring boot application. Everything is working find but my application contains some pdf reports which I try to open in iframe it is not allowing and showing error : "This page has been blocked by Microsoft Edge". It is not working in any browser. Could anyone please help me what settings do I have to do to make it working?

In my servlet code I have tried to add below setting but not working:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

Also in application.properties file I have added below code:

```
com.atlassian.jira.clickjacking.protection.disabled: true
jira.security.csp.sandbox.disabled: true
com.atlassian.jira.clickjacking.protection.exclude: /pdf
```

And pdf is generated dynamically every time and it is coming in output stream byte format. Please let me know what settings need to be done to make it work.

Comment: @KJ, thank you but Outside Jira it is working fine in normal tab but inside Jira I am getting this issue so it something related to Jira plugin.